# Multi file upload with description to each file

Tags: php, mysql, html

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" />
<input type="text" name="description[]" />

<input type="file" name="file[]" />
<input type="text" name="description[]" />
```

and should the name of them be the same name
bacause actully i have one is appear to the end user and the others it clones when the end user clike on " + button" so the others are Cloned with the same name and every thing

so how can I get the info from the form like this:
File#1 - description
File#2 - description
File#2 - description

also i don't have just the description below each file
i have select menu and and other.

and i want to get all these info for each file

I have this for input file:

```
while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES[image][name])){

if(!empty($value)){
$filename = $value;

// Result here

}}
```

I asked before [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425573/how-to-get-the-multi-values-multi-fields) but the solution should i change the name items[0][type] items[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425573/how-to-get-the-multi-values-multi-fields)[type] like this and as I said earlier I Should not change the name

this is for other fields:

```
<select name="items[0][type]"> 
<input name="items[0][color]">  
<select name="items[1][type]"> 
<input name="items[1][color]"> 

foreach ($_POST['items'] as $item) { 
    $type = $item['type']; 
    $color = $item['color']; 
}
```

but as i said this not helpfull because the name not unified

I want to grab all the information from the form for each file

its so important to me to know how this work
can anybody help me

thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($counter=0; $counter<count($_POST['description']); $counter++) 
{
    if(isset($_FILES['file']['name'][$counter]) && $_FILES['file']['name'][$counter])
    {
       $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$counter]; 
       $description = $_POST['description'][$counter]; 
    }
}
```